# Selenium verify that div has a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm trying to verify that particular div has a scrollbar, how to do it with Selenium?
Element:

```
<div class="checkout-mini-cart">
```

Code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;
String script = "var div = document.getElementsByClassName('.checkout-mini-cart');" +
                "return div.scrollHeight < div.clientHeight;";
Object isScrollable = jsExecutor.executeScript(script);
```

It always return false because "return div.scrollHeight;" returns null. How to do it in a correct way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array and not a DOM element.

To check if an element is scroll-able with a script injection :

```
String JS_ELEMENT_IS_SCROLLABLE = 
    "return arguments[0].scrollHeight > arguments[0].offsetHeight;";

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;

WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".checkout-mini-cart"));
Boolean isScrollable = (Boolean)jse.executeScript(JS_ELEMENT_IS_SCROLLABLE, container);
```

or by reading the properties :

```
WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".checkout-mini-cart"));
int scrollHeight = parseInt(container.getAttribute("scrollHeight"));
int offsetHeight = parseInt(container.getAttribute("offsetHeight"));
Boolean isScrollable = scrollHeight> offsetHeight;
```