# Height of scroll bar

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, selenium

**Background**: There are many scroll bars on the page.

First Scroll doesn't start from the top of the page. The page has some header that always remains on top and below it, scrolling starts. Inside this scrolling area there more modules that have scroll bars.

**Question**:
How can I verify that there is a scroll bar present for modules and page?

**I tried:**:

```
WebElement container = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("_________"));
int scrollHeight = parseInt(container.getAttribute("scrollHeight"));
int offsetHeight = parseInt(container.getAttribute("offsetHeight"));
Boolean isScrollable = scrollHeight> offsetHeight;
```

Which is provided as solution here: [Selenium verify that div has a scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545251/selenium-verify-that-div-has-a-scrollbar)

But it is giving the same height for each module. What am I doing wrong? If not Java is there a solution using `JavaScriptExecutor`?

Comment: By.cssSelector("_________") I assume you are filling this gap with a valid CSS selector in use?

Comment: Yes. My HTML page is similar to this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height . This page also has scroll bar inside scroll bar.